# Best possible way to read word documents from database

Tags: c#, .net, oracle10g

I have around 200 word documents generated with a console application. Which is the better: to store the document as such in database or just store the path in the file system??

Thanks in advance

Comment: ravendb or some other document database would prolly be a better choice.

Comment: My client uses oracle database. Also I will be running the console application using a windows task scheduler. So each time doc will get updated.So will it create any problem to access the file for eg:exceptions like file aready in use.??

Comment: As with every problem, "it depends".  In which circumstances do you need to extract the data, and work with it?

Comment: I am extracting latest news data from some website. So the data may be changing each hour.My client wants to get the latest data whevever they are using in a doc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 200.  What ever you are more comfortable with.  You can control locks in the file system but probably easier in the db.   If is was 200,000 then would be more reason for file system based on volume.

Comment: Ok..I will be generating only 215 word documents. So your advice is to save the docs as such in database right?

Comment: Yes if you are more comfortable db.

Comment: Thanks Blam.. I will go with db..

Answer (score 0):

You should store the file itself on the file system and just the path to each file in the database.

Comment: hi jsk,can u pls read the comment which i posted above in reply to jeremy.What do u think about that issue?

Comment: In response to your above comment, you will need to make sure you open and close each file appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the actual documents' contents in a database is far more work and stress for the server than storing the filename/location on the database. Done properly you will be able to call the contents of the document into HTML or similar no problem.